# IQueryable with distinct records and ordered

Tags: c#, linq

I've been trying to get an `IQueryable` with distinct and ordered values, but I've found that I can't apply a distinct after `orderby` or I'll lose the order.

The last query I tried was the following:

```
IQueryable<gbd_Pages> Listpagespages = 
      (from c in _db.gbd_Content
       where c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false && 
             c.gbd_Template_Fields.SortOrder == sortOrder
       orderby c.Content ascending
       select c.gbd_Pages);
```

With this I get repeated results.

The table I want returned is `gbd_Pages` which has a relation of 1 to many with `gbd_Content`.
With this I mean that `gbd_Content` will have a foreign key that will have the primary key of `gbd_Pages`.

I need to do a sortOrder by the table gbd_Template_Fields which has a relation 1 to 1 with `gbd_Content`.

Is there a way for me to do this? I need it to be an `IQueryable` without converting to `IEnumerable` or list.

Comment: If you're looking for `gbp_Pages`, then that needs to be your primary `from`. From there you can use `.Any()` in the query against `gbd_Content` and you won't need to do a Distinct.

Comment: @DiskJunky Can you give me an example how to do that please, at the end i need to do a sortOrder with c.gbd_Template_Fields.SortOrder

Comment: If you have 1 to many relationship, how you will order 1 by field of many? It has to be some aggregate, like `Min` ?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev i don't know that is why i'm trying to do this from gbd_Content instead of gbd_Pages. Do you have a solution? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you need is something like this:

```
var query =
    from p in _db.gbd_Pages
    from pc in (from c in p.gbd_Content
               where c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false &&
                     c.gbd_Template_Fields.SortOrder == sortOrder
               orderby c.Content ascending
               select c).Take(1)
    orderby pc.Content ascending
    select p;
```

So you start from `one` side of the relationship (to avoid the need of `Distinct`), then you select a *single* record from the `many` side matching the criteria and having the smaller value of the sorting field (using ordered subquery + `Take(1)`), and finally sort the result using the sort field value from that single child record.

I'm assuming you have inverse collection navigation property from `gbd_Pages` to `gbd_Content`. If you don't, replace the `p.gbd_Content` with `_db.gbd_Content where c.[gbd_Content_FK] == p.[PK]`.

Comment: This seems to be the correct solution. I just need to do some tests first and i can mark this as the correct solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your primary `from` needs to be the `gbd_Pages` table, rather than `gbp_Content` if those are the results that you want to return. I'll have to assume a foreign key here but you'd want to change to something like;

```
IQueryable<gbd_Pages> Listpagespages = _db.gbp_Pages
                                          .Where(p => (from c in _db.gbd_Content
                                                                       where c.IsActive == true 
                                                                          && c.IsDeleted == false 
                                                                       select c.gbd_Pages.PrimaryKeyID)
                                                                      .Any())
                                          .Select(p => new 
                                                  {
                                                      // select specific fields here...
                                                      p,
                                                      SortCol = _db.gbp_Content
                                                                   .FirstOrDefault(c => c.PrimaryKeyID)
                                                                   .Where(c => c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false &&
                                                                          c.gbd_Template_Fields.SortOrder == sortOrder)
                                                                   .Select(c => c.Content)
                                                  })
                                          .OrderBy(v => c.SortCol);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. yes in `gbd_Content` there is a foreign key that is from `gbd_Pages`,  but doing that how can i do the orderby with the content  property that has a specific sortorder from the table gbd_Content?

Comment: It's giving me an error on the .Select:   'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Nmaster88 Updated query. It's a little hard to do on the fly without the schema/code but the adjustment should hopefully work

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
          IQueryable<gbd_Pages> Listpagespages = _db.gbd_Content
                                                .Select (c=>new { c.gbd_Pages })
                                                .Where(c=>c.IsActive == true && c.IsDeleted == false &&c.gbd_Template_Fields.SortOrder == sortOrder)
                                                .Distinct()
                                                .OrderBy(c => c.Content)
                                                .Select(c => c.gbd_Pages)
```

Comment: This approach has an issue in that the `Distinct()` isn't required. Generally speaking using distinct is a code smell from a set theory perspective as it's means you're starting with either too much data to begin with or you're not selecting the correct set as the primary - which is the case here.

Comment: Already tried this, doesn't work, it can give duplicated records